# Visual Studio Code: The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. What does this mean?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've installed Visual Studio Code and Python. But for some reason, when I run a simple print("Hello"), I encounter the following error:

[image]

What is wrong? So far not a single soul that I've spoken to have been able to help me.

I have Python installed and it works when I run simple codes in the python prompt.

I'm I missing something on line 13?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have an empty string after the `&`

Comment: But there exactly? I can't find it

Comment: Your command has `& ''`. The empty string is literally right there after the `&`.

Comment: @takendarkk I can see the $ ' ' but where do I remove this? The code that I'm running is just a print("hello")

Comment: The problem is not in your code, the problem is in the command you are using to run the code. Your command is pointing to C drive, then changing directory, then you have `& ''` for some reason. `c:; cd 'c:\blah'; & ''`. The error message is even underlining the problematic empty string.

Comment: @takendarkk I understand the error, it makes sense now. Do you have any tip on how I correct the command?

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you using the Code Runner extension? Or some other extension for running Python files? Because seems the command for launching Python is garbled.

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by other extensions.

I suggest you delete extensions one by one to find the reason (keep python and pylance).